# How to create scatter plot in R when time (desired x axis) is at the top of my CSV and not in a column?

Tags: r, time-series

I am attempting to use the excel sheet below to graph bacteria growth curves from different locations, in different concentrations (25uM and 100uM (not shown)).  The Rep# as the column names indicates an OD measurement at that specific hour Rep1 = hour 1, Rep4 = hour 4.
I am not sure how to set this up to where R understands that my time variable is not in its own column.

I am attempting to get this answered otherwise I will have to rearrange the excel sheet and I am trying to avoid that due to the large amount of data.

[image]

I am fairly new to the R language and usually can google my way out of a problem that I am having but haven't been able to figure this one out.  I tried using the ts() function but I cannot seem to get anywhere with that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Data cleaning / preprocessing / visualization in R is usually much easier to do when your data is in *long format* (having one column indicating the replicate and another column containing an OD value, rather than 5 OD columns that correspond to different replicates).

The pivot_longer function from the tidyr package is helpful for this.

```
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(
    "Plant" = sample(c("One", "Two", "Three"), size = 50, replace = TRUE),
    "Location" = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), size = 50, replace = TRUE),
    Rep1 = rnorm(50),
    Rep2 = rnorm(50),
    Rep3 = rnorm(50),
    Rep4 = rnorm(50),
    Rep5 = rnorm(50)
)

long_df <- pivot_longer(
    data = df,    
    cols = -c(Plant, Location), 
    names_to = c("Replicate"), 
    values_to = "OD"
)
```

The `cols` parameter indicates we want pivot_longer to try and lengthen all the columns in the dataframe that aren't "Plant" or "Location". You'll want to extend the list to all your other columns that aren't starting with "Rep".

The function will convert the Rep1, Rep2, Rep3, ... columns into a single column called "Replicate" (that's what the names_to parameter is for).
The values inside those Rep1, Rep2, ... columns will move into a new column called OD.

From there, I would use the ggplot2 package to make the scatter plot.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot2(
    df,
    mapping = aes(x = Replicate, y = OD)
) + geom_point()
```

As an aside, I would recommend changing the name of your "Rep" column (the one that just has 1s and 2s) manually in advance of this to avoid confusion with the other Rep1, Rep2, ... columns.